# Changing browser mode for IE9 but not IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-9, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

Here's a quickie. Is there a way to tell IE9 to change its display mode, but NOT IE10? We ran into an issue where some things were not working in IE10 because while IE9 emulating IE8 works fine, IE10 emulating IE8 does not. If I remove the metatag it works in IE10 but IE9 will have problems.

This is the tag in question:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`

Comment: this sounds like a situation where it would be better to work out what the problem is and how to fix it, rather than trying to hack your way out of trouble. What is the problem that is making you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try  [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: What seemed to work is <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8,IE10" />